# if $f(x)$ is continuously differentiable in $[0,\infty)$, and $\int_{0}^{\infty}f$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty}f'$ converge

Tags: improper-integrals

if $f(x)$ is continuously differentiable in $[0,\infty)$, and $\int_{0}^{\infty}f$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty}f'$ converge, find a counter example to the claim that $\lim \limits_{x\rightarrow \infty}f'(x) = 0$.

I tried $x\sin(e^x)$ as $f'$, but I don't know if the primitive function improper integral converges, or even if it has a primitive function.

tnx in advance

Comment: Please put the whole question in the main body.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $f$ be a non-negative differentiable function such that $f'$ is continuous and $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty}f'(x)\,dx$ exist.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2751909/let-f-be-a-non-negative-differentiable-function-such-that-f-is-continuous-a)

Comment: @Gary honestly i'm at the same situation as the OP of that thread. I haven't learned yet function sequences, and the second comment is just way too complex for someone who learned improper integrals two weeks ago. I hoped there were an elementric example

Comment: Is there a requirement that $f$ be non-negative? (Does the interval $[0,\infty)$ refer to the domain or codomain of $f$?). If not, then counterexamples are easier.

Comment: @bjorn93 this isn't a requirment, and it's the domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the following is simple enough for you. I'll be using the convergence of these well-known integrals:
$$I_1=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx\qquad I_2=\int_0^{\infty}\cos(x^2)\,dx $$
(They are called [Dirichlet integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral) and [Fresnel integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral), respectively.)
Let
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{\sin(x^2)}{x},\quad x\ne0\\0,\quad\quad\qquad x=0\end{cases} $$
Then
$$f'(x)=\begin{cases}2\cos(x^2)-\dfrac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2},\quad x\ne0\\1,\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\qquad x=0\end{cases} $$
You can verify that $f$ and $f'$ are continuous.
$\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$ doesn't exist since $\lim_{x\to\infty}\cos(x^2)$ doesn't exist and $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}=0$. Regarding the convergence,
$$\int_0^{\infty}f(x)\,dx=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x}\,dx $$
transforms to $\frac 12I_1$ with the substitution $x=\sqrt{t}$.
$$\int_0^{\infty}f'(x)\,dx=2\int_0^{\infty}\cos(x^2)\,dx-\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}$$
The first integral on the RHS is $I_2$. For the other one, integration by parts gives
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}=\sin(x^2)\left(-\frac 1x\right)\bigg\rvert_0^{\infty}+\int_0^{\infty}\frac{2x\cos(x^2)}{x}\,dx\\
=2\int_0^{\infty}\cos(x^2)\,dx$$
so it's convergent as well (and equal to $2I_2$).